# Vim function normal mode then execute

Tags: vim

I have the following code:

```
function CSVTableFunc(command)
    let cursor = getpos('.')
    let l:winview = winsaveview()
    normal(ggVG)
    execute a:command
    call setpos('.', cursor)
    call winrestview(l:winview)
endfunction
```

Basically, what it does is it selects all lines from top to bottom, then executes the command that's passed in the function.

However, before the command is executed, the lines selected before hand are deselected.

What's the thing that I've missed?

Cheers!

Comment: `gv` will re-select the previously selected region. however if your `command` was something like `d`, there is nothing to select.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply! just to give context, im calling the function as `CSVTableFunc("CSVTable")` with `CSVTable` as the command from the vim plugin: https://github.com/chrisbra/csv.vim

Comment: does adding a line `normal! gv` to the end of your function help?

Comment: sadly it does not :(
Is there a one-liner way to do something like `execute "normal ggVG <execute a:command>"`?

Comment: you can make the command support range. then you don't need select any longer. just pass `%`

Comment: Hi, author of csv.vim here. Perhaps you should explain you actual problem, that you are trying to solve with your function.

Comment: Hello @ChristianBrabandt, I want to have a shortcut for the `:CSVTable` and `:CSVTabularize` command with something like `noremap <leader>[ :call CSVTableFunc("CSVTable")<CR>`

Comment: And something like this: `:nnoremap <leader>[ :CSVTable<cr>` does not work?

Comment: Thanks for your help and awesome plugin BTW! :D
I've tried that but it removes the first and last line in the rendered Table.

Answer (score 0):

A couple problems here.

First, you attempted to use `normal(...)` as if it's a function. It's not (and if it was, you used it wrong anyway, you'd be missing a `call` command).

What you actually told Vim was to run the following normal-mode commands:

`(` - back a sentence

`ggVG` - roughly, select all text in the buffer

`)` - forward a sentence

Some experimentation shows this probably actually doesn't cause any problems, but it's wrong, and it could cause problems in other circumstances.

Your bigger problem is that commands don't actually operate on a range unless you tell them to. In visual mode (i.e. when you've selected a range of lines), when you press <kbd>:</kbd> you automatically get `'<,'>` inserted on the command line. This text says "run the command on the visual selection".

Using `execute` does not automatically insert this range. You'd need to manually put the range at the beginning of the command, if the command supports a range. Since you did not do this, your command only runs with its default range, which is usually the current line. In your case, since you did `ggVG` before running your command, you probably see the command run on the last line only.

Anyway, you don't need the visual selection. Just use the special range `%` instead of selecting anything. `%` means "on every line".

The problem is, some commands may not support a range. For those commands, you will probably need to use a loop, or a `:g` command, to run the command on each line of interest one by one.